# changing font size and style in picker view

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

How can I change font style and size of picker view?  I don't see an option in the picker view settings.  Can you set it programmatically? I'm using swift 3 and 
xcode 8.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change font style and size in function:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
```

For example:

```
let pickerDataSource: [String] = (1...10).map { "Option " + String(format: "%2d", $0)}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = (view as? UILabel) ?? UILabel()

    label.textColor = .red
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

    label.text = pickerDataSource[row]

    return label
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got:   var choices = ["SortBy:", "Date(ascending)", "Date(descending)","Calories Burned(descending)","Duration(descending)"] how do I put that into my picker view?

Comment: @jean Please try: ```let pickerDataSource: [String] = ["Date(ascending)", "Date(descending)","Calories Burned(descending)","Duration(descending)"]```